# Query to Find number of entries in last 7 days from first entry

Tags: mysql

I have a table that have userid and time as 2 columns. Time contains the entry when the row was created. I want to find the number of entries created for every userid within 7 days of the first entry created for that user.

```
+--------+----------+
|userid  |date      |
+--------+----------+
|1       | 1st Apr  |
|2       | 2nd Apr  |
|1       | 2nd Apr  |
|1       | 2nd Apr  |
|1       | 3rd Apr  |
+--------+----------+
```

Suppose we need to print the count for 2 respective days from 1st entry:
The output should be:

```
+--------+----------+
|userid  |count     |
+--------+----------+
|1       | 3        | //3 entries for 1st and 2nd Apr
|2       | 1        | //1 entry for 3rd Apr
+--------+----------+
```

NOTE: I need to do this in a single query.

Comment: What do you have so far in terms of a Query?

Comment: I don't know how to start this. To do this from a fixed date is easy. But the problem I am facing is that every user will have different window of time.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I hope the edit makes my question clear.

Comment: are you ready to store your date as a specific format like YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ? so that we can find out a way to get the data for last 7 days

Comment: Yes. I just provided a dummy data.

Comment: @KrishnaKhowal Please amend your question accordingly. Dummy data is fine, just not that dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT([Date]) as count_entries, t.[user_id]
    FROM User_Time t
      WHERE [date] 
        BETWEEN 
            (SELECT MIN([date]) 
                    FROM User_Time 
                        WHERE [user_id] = t.[user_id]) 
        AND 
            (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7, MIN([date])) 
                 FROM User_Time 
                       WHERE [user_id] = t.[user_id])
    GROUP BY [user_id]
```

Sorry, I don't have MySQL at the moment, but I hope you can adapt it changing DATEADD to DATE_ADD.